# XSLT test a value of an element

Tags: xslt

I've got a following xml:

```
<company 
    <division>
        ...
        <employees>
            <employee>
                <company>First supplier</company>
                <fee>10000.00</fee>     
                <vat>yes</vat> <!-- Is the contractor a VAT payer (yes/no) -->
            </employee>
        </employees>
    </division>
</company>
```

and I would like to make a html output file from it via xslt. My problem is that I want to test, if the `vat` is `yes` or `no` and based on the value I would like to print message `is (not) a VAT payer`. Bellow is what I've got now, but it's not working.

```
<xsl:template match="/company/division/employees/employee">
    <xsl:value-of select="./company"/>, contractor fee <xsl:value-of select="./fee"/>, is<xsl:if test="./vat=no"> not</span></xsl:if> a VAT payer
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just missing some quotes around your 'no' value in your `xsl:if`. I also added a missing `<span>` tag and removed the unnecessary `./` prefixes of you select expressions. Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/company/division/employees/employee">
    <xsl:value-of select="company" />, contractor fee <xsl:value-of select="fee" />, is<xsl:if test="vat='no'"><span> not</span></xsl:if> a VAT payer
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: mygod ... thanks :) I've had a quotes there before, but it threw some errors ... but now I think it was not relevant to the quotes I've removed :D